# Float a gif image over a HTML page

Tags: html, css

I want to have a GIF that stays in the centre of the page regardless of where the user scrolls.  I want there to be the illusion that the image is 'floating above the page' rather than it being on it.

I believe CSS would be the way to go about doing this?  Assuming a have an image called `foo.gif`, what would the CSS be to do this?

Comment: Do you mean *floating* like with a [drop shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_shadow)? What did you try so far? [`position:fixed`](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/), [`margin:auto`](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html), ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more specific guidance on what you want, and why, the best I can offer is:

```
img {
    position: fixed; /* forces the element to stay fixed in relation to the viewport */
    top: 50%; /* sets the top of the image 50% of the page height */
    left: 50%; /* sets the left side of the image 50% across the page */
    margin-left: -100px; /* moves the image half of its own width to the left-side of the page */
    margin-top: -93px; /* moves the image half its height 'up' the page */
    box-shadow: 0.5em 0.5em 0.7em #333; /* to give the illusion of 'floating'
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3XHu2/).

Answer (score 1):

It works with **iiz**'s solution if you change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzPc3/) for you to see.

I also included a drop shadow ([from here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/)) to make the image "float".

It's all a bit pasted together, but it will work and you can alter it in any way you wish...